# Can I make android offline voice recognition API public?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I have found documentation for using android offline voice recognition in Java Application [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/srec.git/+/master) in doc/UAPI_User_Guide.pdf. As I understand I can't use it in Android application (it is not availiable in the SDK). Am I right? Can I write my own Android module that makes wrapper for this API and makes it visible for user applications? I use my own board. Such an approach is acceptable to me. Is there any documentation on how to write such modules?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Offline voice recognition is available for developers to use as of Android Jellybean, so there really is no point...

To do this you must implement SpeechRecognizer which will use offline detection when available.

For reference: http://www.androidcentral.com/google-search-update-allows-third-party-developers-use-offline-speech-recognition http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html